# Java Exception: get detailMessage only

Tags: java

I am trying to get only `detailMessage` from an Exception:

```
} catch (Exception e) {
    logger.error(failed  + e.getCause().getMessage()); }
```

The log file contains

> "Unable to find element with name == filter:P_ClearButtonDFI (WARNING:
>   The server did not provide any stacktrace information) Command
>   duration or timeout: 30.24 seconds For documentation on this error,
>   please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
>   Build info: version: '2.47.1', revision: '411b314', time: '2015-07-30
>   03:03:16' System info: host: 'OACVWMAX10006', ip: '10.29.19.64',
>   os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1',
>   java.version: '1.7.0_79'
>   *** Element info: {Using=name, value=filter:P_ClearButtonDFI} Session ID: 5149a0b8-475e-4d89-a9d6-e5115e773da8 Driver info:
>   org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver Capabilities
>   [{platform=WINDOWS, javascriptEnabled=true, elementScrollBehavior=0,
>   ignoreZoomSetting=false, enablePersistentHover=true,
>   ie.ensureCleanSession=false, browserName=internet explorer,
>   enableElementCacheCleanup=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=dismiss,
>   version=9, ie.usePerProcessProxy=false,
>   ignoreProtectedModeSettings=false, cssSelectorsEnabled=true,
>   requireWindowFocus=false, initialBrowserUrl=http://localhost:21733/,
>   handlesAlerts=true, ie.forceCreateProcessApi=false, nativeEvents=true,
>   browserAttachTimeout=0, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches=,
>   takesScreenshot=true}]"

but I only want

> Unable to find element with name == filter:P_ClearButtonDFI

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think there is any elegant way to access it.

Of course you may use Java reflection to access the private field `Throwable.detailMessage` but this far from being elegant :)

I work in Spring where exceptions often inherit `org.springframework.core.NestedRuntimeException` which creates its message like

```
detailedMessage + "; nested exception is " + cause.detailedMessage 
    ... + "; nested exception is " + cause.detailedMessage
```

I created a simple method

```
private String extractDetailedMessage(Throwable e) {
    final String message = e.getMessage();
    if (message == null) {
        return "";
    }
    final int tailIndex = StringUtils.indexOf(message, "; nested exception is");
    if (tailIndex == -1) {
        return message;
    }
    return StringUtils.left(message, tailIndex);
}
```

You can easily modify it for your case :) I'm afraid you do not have anything nicer...

Answer (score 4):

Here is a nice little Kotlin extension function for the same code shared by Honza Zidek

```
fun NestedRuntimeException.detailMessage(): String 
    = this.message.orEmpty().substringBefore("; nested exception is")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Apache commons](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) as well:

```
String detailMessage = StringUtils.substringBefore(e.getMessage(), "; nested exception is");
```

Answer (score -1):

Use reflection to read `Throwable.detailMessage` from `NestedRuntimeException`

```java
String detailMessage = (String) FieldUtils.getDeclaredField( Throwable.class, "detailMessage", true ).get(e);
```

`FieldUtils` refers to `org.apache.commons.lang3.reflect.FieldUtils` from Apache Common Lang3